# Swift: Two animations once after another

Tags: swift, swift4, swift4.2

I have this little animation issue, where I get stuck.
I want to show two animation, one after the other (first swiping a card from the button to the center and then fliping it).
So I'm using the completion in the UIView.animate method, to trigger the second animation, once the first animation is done. But in the simulator it shows every time only the second animation. Can somebody help out?
Thanks a lot

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    let animation:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint:CGPoint(x: self.imgBackOfTheCard.frame.midX, y: 1200))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint:CGPoint(x: self.imgBackOfTheCard.frame.midX, y: self.imgBackOfTheCard.frame.midY))
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    animation.duration = 1
    self.imgBackOfTheCard.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            let transitionOptionsLeft: UIView.AnimationOptions = [.transitionFlipFromLeft, .showHideTransitionViews]
            UIView.transition(from: self.imgBackOfTheCard, to: self.imgFrontCard, duration: 1, options: transitionOptionsLeft, completion: nil)
        })
})
```

Comment: Remove the completion. Does the first animation work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing CA animation and UIView animation.

The first animation is a `CABasicAnimation`. `UIView.animate` doesn't recognise it, so the first animation is "done" (as far as `UIView.animate` is concerned) immediately and the completion closure is called. Now you do another `UIView` animation. But actually, the first animation is just starting, so the second animation takes over and you only see the second one.

To fix this, you should move the first animation out of the `UIView.animate` block:

```
let animation:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint:CGPoint(x: self.imgBackOfTheCard.frame.midX, y: 1200))
animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint:CGPoint(x: self.imgBackOfTheCard.frame.midX, y: self.imgBackOfTheCard.frame.midY))
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
animation.duration = 1
self.imgBackOfTheCard.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
```

And then wait for 1 second, then do the second animation:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
   // do your second animation here.
})
```

---

Upon further inspection, the first animation doesn't have to be a `CABasicAnimation`. It can be created with `UIView.animate` as well. Just set the `frame` property.